Are there some copulas that you cannot take the contrapositive of?
Are there some copulas or relations that you cannot take the contrapositive of ?
For consider the following:

a stands for every
e stands for some
n stands for negation
R stands for relation
Addition stands for disjunction
Multiplication stands for conjunction
Let D stand for dove
Let R stand for has
Let W stand for wings
aDReW or every dove has some wings. It seems that it doesn’t make sense to take the contrapositive of this.
Let N stand for X is a natural number
Let R stand for has
Let P stand for prime number greater than X
aNReP or every X that is a natural number has some prime number greater than it. It seems that it doesn’t make sense to take the contrapositive of this either.


To take the "contrapositive of a copula", you need a 'copula'/relation R between statements, like → in the usual contrapositive. Then pRq can be transformed into ~qR~p for any R. But your "every dove has some wings" is ∀x∃y(D(x) ∧ W(y) ∧ H(x,y)) and has no 'copula', H(x,y) is a relation between objects, not between statements.

@Conifold, not true though. For consider the statement every natural number is identical to some integer. The copula in this example is "is". The contrapositive of this statement would seem to be every non-integer is identical to some non-natural number.

@Conifold, or consider the statement every cat is identical to some mammal. The contrapositive would be every non-mammal is some non-cat.

@Conifold, or we can consider every cat is a mammal. The copula is "is". Thus, the contrapositive is every non-mammal is a non-cat.

See Syllogism for the proper way of symbolizing categorical propositions.

If that is your idea of 'contrapositive' then what stops you from making "every non-wing has some non-doves" the 'contrapositive' of "every dove has some wings". Non-wings do usually have non-dove parts. You are not expecting that doing this with arbitrary transitive verb would preserve the truth of the statement, are you?

As I said elsewhere, the word "identical" needlessly complicates this question. "Is an instance of" is more commonly used in mathematical logic.

The examples you give are unproblematic. The contrapositive of "every dove has some wings" is "every wingless thing is not a dove". The contrapositive of "every cat is a mammal" is "every non-mammal is a non-cat".
The sentence, "every natural number has a prime number that is greater than it" has a more complex structure. Its contrapositive would be "every thing that has no prime number greater than it is not a natural number". This sounds weird to be sure, but it is not incorrect.
"Every natural number is identical to some integer" has the contrapositive, "every thing that is not an integer is identical to something that is not a natural number". Again, it sounds a little weird, but it is not incorrect.
Your examples are not limited to copulas. "Every dove has wings" does not include a copula. But it is very similar to, "every dove is a winged thing," which does.
There are different ways we can handle examples like this in formal logic. One is to deploy set theory and say that the set of all doves is a subset of the set of all winged things. From this it follows that the set of all wingless things is a subset of the set of all non-doves. (I'm simplifying a little here, because in practice mathematicians are cautious when talking about the complement of a set and they like to specify the universe.)
In modern quantifier logic, it is standard practice to treat predications such as "every dove has wings" as a relation between propositions. It might be symbolised as (∀x)(Dove(x) → Winged(x)). Its contrapositive is (∀x)(¬Winged(x) → ¬Dove(x)). This approach treats a universal statement as a conditional, i.e. "For any x, if x is a dove then x is winged". Contraposition is then handled as a property of the conditional connective, i.e. "A → B" entails "¬B → ¬A" and vice versa. (At least in classical logic.) This approach of treating contraposition as a feature of the conditional connective is much more flexible and expressive than that of Aristotelian syllogistic logic.
A potential limitation of the modern approach using conditionals lies in the fact that not all conditionals obey the same logic, so we can get counterexamples to contraposition, just not the kind you gave. Consider, "if it rained yesterday, then it did not rain very hard". Plausible, if we return from vacation and find the garden to be dry. But its contrapositive is, "if it rained very hard yesterday, then it did not rain". On the face of it highly implausible. Or similarly, "if I go to the party then I won't stay long". The contrapositive is, "if I stay long then I won't go to the party". In both cases, the contrapositive appears to be unacceptable because the consequent part of the conditional is already taken to be false under the assumption of the antecedent.
Another way contraposition can fail is for propositions that are uncertain. "It is highly probable that if A then B" does not entail, "It is highly probable that if not-B then not-A". Since in the real world propositions and conditionals are frequently uncertain, care must be taken to use the appropriate logic.
